# Using filter in a Laravel collection

Tags: laravel, collections

This is the following code:

```php
$apartment_list->filter(function ($apartament) use ($services) {
    if (isset($apartament) && $apartament->services[0]->id = $services) {
        return $apartament;
    }
});
```

this is an example of my $apartment_list:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "user_id": null,
  "title": "Non sunt vitae quia.",
  "slug": "non-sunt-vitae-quia",
  "rooms": 3,
  "bathrooms": 2,
  "beds": 11,
  "squared_meters": 50,
  "address": "14235 Emory Villages Suite 671\nMillerbury, RI 40415-0580",
  "latitude": "-75.191525",
  "longitude": "-105.046424",
  "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/800x800.png/0011aa?text=eveniet",
  "is_visible": 1,
  "floor": 4,
  "price": 1138,
  "description": "Dolor fuga cumque delectus doloremque ratione minima. Ut voluptatum porro id et est nam. Dolor unde corrupti excepturi ratione quo.\n\nVoluptatem mollitia omnis ipsa tempore nihil nisi. Ut ullam ut et unde. Est dolores tempore molestiae est omnis.\n\nEst autem ut porro voluptas qui. Ducimus possimus quia vel a beatae id eligendi. Facilis accusamus velit tempora et explicabo architecto. Dolorem at quia esse ipsa officiis est reiciendis.\n\nVoluptate voluptatum minus qui ut velit. Voluptas et quis sint modi culpa. Odit est qui est unde sequi. Eveniet et voluptates est vero.",
  "created_at": "2022-02-22T21:26:06.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2022-02-22T21:26:06.000000Z",
  "services": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "WiFi",
      "slug": "wifi",
      "created_at": "2022-02-22T21:26:06.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-02-22T21:26:06.000000Z",
      "pivot": {
        "apartment_id": 1,
        "service_id": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "sponsors": []
},
```

this code simply transform my services id to 1, without doing his job.
how can I fix it?

I'd like to know also how write better `$apartament->services[0]->id` to have access at my attributes.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `$apartament->services[0]->id == $services`, with two equals signs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
apartment_list->filter(function ($value, $key) use ($services) { 
    return $apartament->id ===  $value->id; 
});
```